# window.open function not working after chrome update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open

Few days ago I updated my chrome browser and before updating my all the programs working properly but after updated to new version (Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)) window.open is not working for the past 1-2 days. I have gone through many solutions which are available on many sites but I am not able to fix this issue. How can I fix this issue?

```
var table_div = document.getElementById("table_div");
newWin= window.open("");
newWin.document.write(table_div.outerHTML);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
```

Comment: Testing `window.open("")` in the console works for me. Are you sure the problem is with this specific function?

Comment: Sometimes Chrome asks you if the page is allowed to open Popups. It's visible at the right side of the URL - Input field.

Comment: actually its chrome bug not js problem